# Why is a word starting with a vowel sound proceeded by 'an'?

Tags: phonology, sandhi

I have read that the the modern 'an' derives from the Old English 'ān', which is also the source of 'one'. So I guess I can see how "one hour; one apple" could work, but that doesn't explain 'why'. What is the function of having one indefinite article for words starting with consonant sounds, and another of words starting with vowel sounds? I did some searching around but the entries I found cited when you use should 'a' vs 'an' but not the why.

Comment: The first article I came across on a Google search, [ef.com](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/indefinite-articles/), has: 'In English, the two indefinite articles are _a_ and _an_. Like other articles, indefinite articles are invariable. You use one or the other, depending on the first letter of the word following the article, **for pronunciation reasons**.  [emphasis mine] There are two ways of pronouncing 'a', neither of which would go well before 'apple'. There are _three_ ways ...

Comment: of pronouncing 'the' - unmarked, stressed, and the one used before a vowel. But one spelling covers all three pronunciations adequately, there being no n-sound etc.

Comment: Basically, people trip over their tongues when they try to do it the "wrong" way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linguistic changes, including sound changes, come naturally. There’s no function for having two forms of the indefinite article. This is probably not the answer you’re looking for, but it is so because it is so.

As for the “why”, linguists are also not 100% sure, but many point to the [principle of least effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_effort). One of the most common effects of this principle is [cluster reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_reduction): perhaps for most people it’s easier to pronounce *a man* than *an man*, whereas *an hour* doesn’t contain a cluster to be reduced.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this sort of thing appears in many languages. Latin has 'a / ab' meaning 'from, by', where 'a' is used before consonants, and 'ab' before vowels. Similarly, Classical Greek has 'οὐκ / οὐ', meaning 'not' where, once again, 'οὐκ' is used before vowels, and 'οὐ' before consonants.

Answer (score 0):

There are not two different indefinite articles.  Both *a* and *an* have the same origin; but before a consonant the /n/ has been lost — much like the /v/ in *of* in ordinary speech.